# Make body occupy 100% of the scrollable page

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page with

```
html,body{ height: 100%; }
```

But I have more content in the page than it can fit at 100%, so there is a vertical scroll bar. This is fine, but right before `</body>` I have a `<footer>Some text</footer>`. My problem is, the footer appears in the middle of the screen even though it's supposed to be showing at the very bottom of the page. I checked, there is no `margin` applied to any element that would push the footer that high up in the body.

What's weird to me is, when I use the Chrome Developer tools to inspect the page it shows the area covered by the body not to be the 100% of the scrollable area. This area is 100% of the page if there was no scroll bar.

I can't provide the markup, it's a legacy ASP.Net application and it's messy.

Comment: <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 1px solid black;"></div>

Comment: We don't need to see the ASP, just the resultant HTML and CSS.

Comment: http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/layout.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `min-height: 100%` instead. On html and body. Also it appears footer is absolutely positioned, but min-height should fix this.

If it doesnt afterwards then apply padding-bottom to body and increase it until footer is where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on how you want to solve this. If you know the page will always be shorter than the content you could move the footer down to the bottom with:

```
footer {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Alternatively this is a task for flexbox (provided you can drop old browsers). Something like this should do the trick:

```
body {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
.main {
   flex-grow: 1;
}
```